# External site with CNAME for site hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

We have an app hosted on *mygreatapp.com*;

We want to have another company use our app in their domain but pointing to our app e.g. *greatapp.theircompany.com*;

I suppose that it would be done adding a CNAME...

How do I do this in a way that the *greatapp.theircompany.com* would use their SSL certificate?

At the moment, when I use the CNAME (pointing *greatapp.theircompany.com* to *mygreatapp.com*), it still use the SSL from *mygreatapp.com*

I tried using Cloudfront, pointing to *mygreatapp.com* and then pointing *greatapp.theircompany.com* to the Cloudfront, both using Cloudfront certificate or a certificate for *greatapp.theircompany.com*, setting a CNAME on Cloudfront etc. but when I try to access it by HTTPS it gives me a 502.

best regards, Níkolas

Comment: *"when I try to access it by HTTPS it gives me a 502"* suggests that you have whitelisted the `Host` header for forwarding to the origin (in the CloudFront 
cache behavior settings) but have overlooked the need to have the certificate at the origin server match the `Host` header value, in that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [subject alternate name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html) to your certificate.  You can do that by giving cloudfront a certificate for mygreatapp.com when you issue a new certificate for greatapp.theircompany.com.  You want the main CN to be greatapp.theircompany.com and include mygreatapp.com in the SAN list.  Be sure to bring over any domains that may already exist in the SAN list as well, or you will break those sites.